# Huge performance spike with EventSystem.Update() just on the first screen touch on Android

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity-game-engine

On my 2D platformer for android I have a huge performance spike when I touch the screen for the first time. After that a small lag occures once and than the game is running smoothly. No error messages.

I already tried to asign graphic raycaster just to certain buttons which helped a bit. But the small lag is still present. In the profiler the performance spike is under the scripts and is marked as the EventSystem.Update(). here is the screenshot from the

[image: Unity Profiler]

On button click I use the following code as the UI Manager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menu;
    public GameObject options;
    public GameObject pause;
    public Animator animatorMain;
    public Animator animatorOptions;
    public Animator animatorPause;
    public bool hide;
    public bool show;

    public void UIDefaults()
    {
        menu = GameObject.Find("MainMenu");
        options = GameObject.Find("optionsMenu");
        pause = GameObject.Find("pauseMenu");

        animatorMain = menu.GetComponent<Animator>();
        animatorOptions = options.GetComponent<Animator>();
        animatorPause = pause.GetComponent<Animator>();

        hide = true;
        show = false;
    }

    /* --- EXIT APPLICATION --- */
    public void Exit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
    /* --- EXIT APPLICATION --- */

    /* --- MAIN MENU --- */
    public void OpenMainMenu()
    {
        UIDefaults();
        animatorOptions.SetBool("OptionsBool", hide);
        StartCoroutine("WaitMainMenu");
    }

    // line 28. Coroutine
    IEnumerator WaitMainMenu()
    {
        // wait for Options menu animation to end.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.15f); 

        SetMainMenuActive();
    }

    // line 35. function to Start the Main menu animation.
    void SetMainMenuActive()
    {
        menu.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
        options.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
        pause.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;

        animatorMain.SetBool("MainBool", show);
        animatorOptions.SetBool("StartOptions", show);
        animatorOptions.SetBool("OptionsBool", show);
    }
    /* --- MAIN MENU --- */


    /* --- OPTIONS MENU --- */
    public void OpenSettings()
    {
        UIDefaults();
        animatorMain.SetBool("MainBool", hide);
        StartCoroutine("WaitOptions");
    }

    // line 66. Coroutine
    IEnumerator WaitOptions()
    {
        // wait for Main menu animation to end.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.15f); 

        SetOptionsActive();
    }

    // line 73. function to Start the Options menu animation. 
    void SetOptionsActive()
    {
        menu.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
        options.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
        pause.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;

        animatorOptions.SetBool("StartOptions", hide);
    }
    /* --- OPTIONS MENU --- */
}
```

I wish to get rid of the initial one time lag when I touch the screen for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Part of it could be that you are using `GameObject.Find()` to get references to your menu stuff. `GameObject.Find` makes a call back to the engine and can cause performance drops and spikes in the profiler.

Set those references in the inspector instead of finding them when the touch event fires. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @JozefBenko I only edited this post. The author of this answer is AriBaaGames ;)

Comment: @AriBaa Games thanx. I have just a small follow up question. How can I set the references in the inspector. A link would be helpful. When I did my research I found out that, as you mentioned, the GameObject.Find() and coroutines have an effect on the performance and Im trying to find an alternative to that. Well, I hope that your suggestion will solve my problem, if not fully than at least partialy.

Comment: Not the poster of this answer but you basically create a public variable in your script and just access that. In unity you should then have a empty slot for this variable found in your inspector. Just drag & drop whatever gameObject your desired component is attached to onto this slot and it is assigned.
On a side note: `GetComponent` is also a pretty expensive operation. You should avoid it if possible. Same principle applies there.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and for me, it was a call to DateTime.Now somewhere deep in the methods that was slow!
take a look at this:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-il2cpp-system-dot-datetime-dot-now-is-slow-on-the-first-run
I replaced the code with Time.time and it's fixed now.